# Why this insertion sort algorithm outputs None?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

```
def insertion_sort(list):
    for index in range(1,len(list)):
        value = list[index]
        i = index - 1
        while i>=0:
            if value < list[i]:
                list[i+1] = list[i]
                list[i] = value
                i = i - 1
            else:
                break

a = [7,1,3,5,9,2,3]

print(insertion_sort(a))
```

This code is taken from a [Khan Academy video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEA31vHiry4). However, when I try to run it myself both on Jupyter Notebook and IDLE it outputs None. I can't figure out why when it's exactly the same from the video.
Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: You don't have a `return` statement anywhere, so your function always returns `None`. What did you _expect_ it to return?

Comment: return list after else: break

Comment: the comment above is clearly correct - but to clear up any confusion, what you probably meant to do was: call `insertion_sort(a)` (no `print` needed), then `print(a)` to see the result

Comment: I note that the video never uses `print()`, only you used `print()`. See the [7:45 mark and onwards](https://youtu.be/lEA31vHiry4?t=7m45s), where Khan *explains* why the function doesn't return anything as the list is sorted in-place.

Comment: @Martijn: he doesn't *explain* why it doesn't return anything. He *asserts* that it doesn't return anything and also that it sorts in place. Both of those are facts, but if there is a relation between them -- which is what an *explanation* would be -- he leaves it implicit. Nothing stops the function from returning the sorted array, but it doesn't. Why not? Because, *pythonic*. But explaining that would take a lot more video.

Answer (score 5):

Your function doesn't have a `return` statement anywhere. If a function doesn't `return` anything explicitly, it always returns `None`.

And it's almost certainly intentional that this function doesn't return anything.

---

Notice that the function mutates its argument in-place:

```
>>> a = [7,1,3,5,9,2,3]
>>> insertion_sort(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

In Python, it's idiomatic for functions that do this to not return anything. See, for example, builtin methods like `list.sort` and `list.append`.

And notice that [in the cited video](https://youtu.be/lEA31vHiry4?t=7m45s), this is exactly what the instructor does—they don't `print` the result of `insertion_sort`, they just call it, and then look at the value of the variable.

---

Also, in general, functions that mutate a value in-place, like this one, take an imperative verb, like the list method [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort), while functions that leave the argument unchanged but return a transformed value, take a past participle, like the built-in function [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).

So, if this function were named `insertion_sorted`, Python programmers would expect it to leave its argument alone and return a new, sorted list; since it's named `insertion_sort`, they'll expect it to sort its argument in-place and return nothing.

Comment: The video never uses `print()`, and instead drives the function directly from the Python interpreter window exactly as you do in your answer. [Start at 7:45m into the video](https://youtu.be/lEA31vHiry4?t=7m45s).

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK, and…? How does that make any part of this answer wrong, or misleading? I'm happy to add a comment to that effect (although commenting on something that the OP left out of the question is always a bit tricky), but I don't think anything major needs to be changed.

Comment: "And this is almost certainly intentional." To be clear, answerer means that the function `insertion_sort` intentionally does not return a specific value, not that the language intentionally returns None when there's no return statement (although that is also intentional).

Comment: @abarnert: I am *supporting* your answer, not criticising it :-) I had not noticed there was a dv on it (which certainly isn't mine).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah; your comment appeared within  the same minute as a downvote, so I guessed they were related.

Comment: @abarnert: ever the danger of leaving a comment!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Short-term, sure, but in the long term the effect was to improve my answer, which is the whole point of commenting.

Comment: @abarnert: I had the sound of before, but the narrator (Khan himself, older video) explicitly states that the function doesn't return anything because it sorts the list in-place.

Comment: I think it'd be helpful to newbies if it were more explicit that `sorted` really is a (built-in) function, not just a function one could in theory create.

Comment: @leewz: Khan explicitly explores sorting algorithms, which is a great topic for new programmers to explore. Python's built-in `sorted()` is fantastic for most applications, but that shouldn't mean that programmers should not learn about the basics of sorting algorithms (and algorithm efficiency in general).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I mean in the comparison between `list.sort` and `sorted`, it is possible for a newbie to think that `sorted` is a function one _could_ define, rather than one that has _been_ defined already.

Comment: @leewz Does the edit make that clear enough? (And is it worth adding examples from the stdlib or popular third-party libraries instead of just builtins?)

Comment: @abarnert Without a fuller comparison between the two, I think this is good enough.